# Start embed Video in a new Activity

Tags: android, video

I'm using a custom WebView to read an embed video in a fragment. The problem is when I try to fullScreen the video I get it only in the FragmentLayout assigned to the webView so I override the onShowCustomView of my webView to handle it and try to opean a new activity with the given View.

I Have to use a new Activity because the first one have to not be in fullScreen mode and dont use  the attribute  `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If it is a youtube video, it is better to use YoutubePlayer API

Comment: it's not restricted on youtube Videos so i can't use the API